# Admob test ads is not showing on a specific app ,but the same code is working fine on other app

Tags: android, android-studio, admob

Ad-mob test ads is not showing on one of my  app ,but the same code is working fine on my others app,
then I find out that this is  happening because of the app package name ,if I rename the package name then also ads are showing.

Some months ago  the app were showing ads , but app got ads serving limited issue ,then I deleted all the ad units from Admob of the app ,after one week this issue solved ,then I wanted to implement ads again but since then even test ads are not showing.

and I couldn't found an error on logcat so I don't Know what to do

Answer (score 2):

There are two things here.
Either you show test ads via local configuration before initializing the sdk like -

```kotlin
val testDeviceIds = Arrays.asList("Your Test ID from logcat. ")
val configuration = RequestConfiguration.Builder().setTestDeviceIds(testDeviceIds).build()
MobileAds.setRequestConfiguration(configuration)
```

Or add the following in your `app-ads.txt` file.
`google.com, pub-3940256099942544, DIRECT, f08c47fec0942fa0`.

More info here: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads

Comment: I solved the problem b only adding app-ads.txt file ,thank god i have been suffering from two months...

Comment: Great! Can you accept the answer, that would be great.

Answer (score -1):

Admob does not deliver ad when your app live any time. Add test id's and change your application id then test your implementation. When you live your application then restore your application id in gradle and live your app. When your app live on play store admob deliver your ad.